# Capistrano - cannot deploy code because of "Permission denied (publickey)."

Tags: macos, git, ssh, capistrano, bitbucket

When I run capistrano to deploy code to the server, I get this error message:

```
...
** Execute git:check
DEBUG[18c8f63a] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:name/project.git on 107.170.160.89
DEBUG[18c8f63a] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/project/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:name/project.git )
DEBUG[18c8f63a]     Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG[18c8f63a]     fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
DEBUG[18c8f63a] Finished in 0.478 seconds with exit status 128 (failed).
```

I am have admin permissions to the repository. When I run **ssh-add -l**, I see an "/Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)" record.

What's wrong here?

**EDIT:**
When I run `ssh bitbucket.org` on the ubuntu server, I get `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: It's not clear from your question -- can you successfully access the repository on bitbucket outside of Capistrano?  E.g., can you `git clone` the repository from the command line?

Comment: I can push data to the repository, I have an admin access there.

Comment: You would expect to see "permission denied" when running `ssh bitbucket.org` because you would be using the wrong username.  Try `ssh git@bitbucket.org` and see what you get (it should give you an informational message, and I would expect this to work since you can `git push`).